# Hyperref from document to the page of Table of Abbreviations

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am creating a glossary in a big document using *\printnoidxglossaries*. At some point, in the document I want to mention *"The abbreviations can be found in \ref{abbrs}"*. However, if I try to put *\label{abbrs}* close to *\printnoidxglossaries* it does not work. I get the error:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 401.
```

I have not found an easy way to fix it. I want to be able to reference the Table of Abbreviations in the text. I don't need to use ref and label, it is just the way I thought it should be done.

Comment: it would be easy to fix if you provided a small, complete example for a test.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was using `\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}`.

I just added

`\label{chap:custom_name}`

to the first glossary entry and referred to it via

```
The abbreviations can be found in chapter \ref{chap:custom_label} on page \pageref{chap:custom_label}.
```

Whereas the `\pageref` reference worked straight away, I had to set the chapter number right, just before my `\printglossary` statement.